# .NET MVC Culture & Model Binding

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC .NET Core (6), the form values that are submitted are subject to culture variations.
So the model binder will treat 1.5 as 1,5 if the current culture is say german (DE);
Is there any way for us to change the culture on some form submitted values so that in spite of the current culture being german, we still receive 1.5 and not 1,5

We tried setting the culture at the beginning in the method using the following, but the model binding had already converted everything to the current culture(German) :

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

US culture uses strings that have . dot as pointer for decimal values.
European culture (ex. de-DE) uses strings that have , comma pointer for decimal values.

Unless you know the culture, you can't reliably understand the value. You definitely should not just replace commas with dots, because that can change the meaning.

Maybe you can try below code , you will receive 1.5 and not 1,5 in European culture. But in 'en' you will get 15.

```
var visioApiCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
string fromVisioApi = "1,5";
string display = double.Parse(fromVisioApi, visioApiCulture).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

result:

[image]

Comment: This is ok for the UI , but on the server you cannot know what was set from the client. For examp;e if the UI is set  to  German UI cuture and you are trying tho get the Lat/Lng values of a location in Googlemaps, a value of 54.9456 would be regarded as 549456. I think the only reliable way to do this is to use a customer ModelBonder. By the way just doing this works for the UI: fromVisioAp.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); You do not need the extra P.arse